# R Shiny Connection to SQL Error: Login failed for user 'username'

Tags: r, sql-server, shiny, odbc

I have an R Shiny app connecting to SQL database with the following code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
column(12, align = 'center', textInput("userName", "User Name")),
column(12, align = 'center', actionButton("dbConnect", "Connect to Database")))

server <- function(session, input, output) {
observeEvent(input$dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
Server = '123......',
Database = 'example',
UID = input$userName,
PWD = askpass("Enter Database Password"))
}
```

The code properly works for entry of username and then prompts password. However, it does not connect to the database and prompts `Login failed for user 'username'.`

I have ensured that the username and password are correct and connect to the database when entering SQL.

Comment: What does the SQL Server Log say, that has more detail. Is this a SQL Authentication login or a Windows Authentication login (or Azure)?

Comment: It is a SQL authentication. Not sure if this helps you at all but it says ```Warning: error in : nanodbc/nanodbs.cpp:983: 00000: [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server] Login failed for user 'username'``` @Charlieface

Comment: No the SQL Server Logs. You can view them from SSMS see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/view-the-sql-server-error-log-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: You do not show attempting a query. How do you know it doesn't work? (I recognize that you probably did try, but based on my assumptions stated in my answer, I suspect that your query call is missing a connection object or something very similar. Your code here is a syntax error for a couple reasons, so it's hard to be sure.)

Comment: *when entering SQL*? Did you mean Management Studio? Do the credentials work if you hard code it in R.

Comment: How is it going, Jimismyn...? Does anything here help or make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to return a connection?

```
  conn = eventReactive(
    input$dbConnect,
    {
      
      PWD = askpass::askpass("Enter Database Password")
      
      conn = DBI::dbConnect(
        odbc::odbc(), 
        driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
        Server = '123.......',
        Database = 'example',
        port=1433,
        UID = input$userName,
        PWD = PWD
        )
      
      return(conn)
    }
  )
```

You can then use `conn()` in subsequent calls, for example

```
  output$tables=renderText({
    req(conn())
    DBI::dbListTables(conn())
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your sample code is a syntax error,

   ```r
   observeEvent(input$dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
   driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
   Server = '123......',
   Database = 'example',
   UID = input$userName,
   PWD = askpass("Enter Database Password"))
   ```

   should probably be

   ```r
   observeEvent(input$userName, {
     dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
       driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
       Server = '123......',
       Database = 'example',
       UID = input$userName,
       PWD = askpass("Enter Database Password"))
   })
   ```

   but even that won't work.
2. You never store that anywhere, so no query can use it. The `DBI` methods such as `DBI::dbGetQuery` all require the object as their first argument, so you need to put it in a real object. @langtang's suggestion to use `eventReactive` is the right start.
3. You cannot use `askpass` in a shiny app that you intend to deploy. You'll need to use environment variables, `config.yml` (via the `config` R package), or some other ways to pass secrets to the app. (I'm going to ignore this part for the sample code below, but keep it in mind.)

### My suggestion

Store the credentials in a list (as opposed to a database connection object) and include a function that connects, runs the query, then disconnects. While there is a *very little* overhead added for each query, it is very small.

But the bigger reason is this: if you ever plan on providing even simple async operations in your shiny app by including `promise`+`future`, the connection object cannot be transferred to `future` processes, so any query in a promise will fail. However, a `list` of parameters *can* transfer.

So you might try:

```r
myGetQuery <- function(..., cred) {
  tmpcon <- do.call(DBI::dbConnect, c(list(odbc::odbc()), cred))
  on.exit(DBI::dbDisconnect(tmpcon), add = TRUE)
  DBI::dbGetQuery(tmpcon, ...)
}
# similar funcs needed if you need things like: dbExecute,
# dbListTables, dbListFields, etc, elsewhere in your server component
cred <- list(
  driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
  Server = '123......',
  Database = 'example'
)
```

And somewhere in your shiny app, something like:

```r
cred_with_userpass <- reactive({
  c(cred, UID = input$userName,
    PWD = askpass("Enter Database Password"))
})
somedat <- reactive({
  myGetQuery("select 1 as a", cred = cred_with_userpass())
})
```